# JSON array shows both undefined and the data in jquery in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, bootstrap-4

I am very new to JS and jquery as you can see with my question. However, I was trying to load some simple JSON date in my HTML page. I have already done this a few times with some projects but this one displays multiple data with some are undefined.

JSON DATA:

```
{"employment": [

    {
        "date": "June 16, 2014 - Present"
    },
    {
        "company": "SAP/Concur Technologies Inc."
    }

]}
```

Result:

```
June 16, 2014 - Present
undefined
undefined
SAP/Concur Technologies Inc.
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

Please also advised I am using bootstrap. I am not sure if that affects my jquery. I tried console logging it and it shows my correct data but for some reason, HTML displays a lot of undefined. I tried checking the debugger but I can't seem to find the cause of the undefined.

```
$.getJSON("data/data.json", (data)=>{
     loadEmploymentData(data.employment);
    console.log(data.employment);
});

function loadEmploymentData(employmentArray){

    employmentArray.forEach((employment)=>{
        $("#employment").append(`<ul><li>${employment.date}</li>
        <li>${employment.company}</li></ul>`);

                });
};
```

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Do you control the source of the json? Doesn't make sense having an array of objects where each object has one of the needed properties. Would make far more sense to have one object with all properties

Comment: Hi, Yes I do control the source of the JSON. I am not sure what you meant about the objects where each object has one of the needed properties. Any recommendation?

Comment: Oh, I was doing it this way for formatting purposes, so I can get each properties and format them differently.

Comment: That's simple enough to add different classes depending on which property it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the structure to one object with multiple properties in it for each employment position

```js
var data = {
  "employment": [{
      "date": "June 16, 2014 - Present",
      "company": "SAP/Concur Technologies Inc."
    },
    {
      "date": "Jan 16, 1999 - Aug 7, 2012",
      "company": "Some Co."
    }
  ]
}

// no changes were made to this function
function loadEmploymentData(employmentArray) {
  employmentArray.forEach((employment) => {
    $("#employment").append(`<ul><li>${employment.date}</li>
        <li>${employment.company}</li></ul>`);
  });
};
// call function since not doing ajax in this demo
loadEmploymentData(data.employment)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="employment"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried updating my JSON file with the varilable data but it is giving me an invalid JSON data. Does that mean, I would have to add the contents in my js file?

Comment: No...just remove `var data =` in the file. I had to assign it to a variable since I'm not using it as json but the same object you would receive inside the ajax ($.getJSON) request

Comment: Thank you again. I tried it with the structure and received the same result. undefined appeared with the data that I was trying to load.

Comment: not sure why unless your browser is caching the request and seeing old data

Answer (score 0):

It's the way you are formatting your JSON. You have a list of object with different properties and you are trying to display all properties in each object so you will got undefined in each iteration you can try

```
{"employment": [

{
    "date": "June 16, 2014 - Present",
    "company": "SAP/Concur Technologies Inc."
},
{
    "date": "JuLy 14, 2014 - Freez",
    "company": "team/rock Technologies Inc."
}


]}
```